# Feed DataProvider with data from SQL query

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng-dataprovider

I am currently researching `DataProvider (TestNG)` and I have done some exercises with it. I have fed `DataProvider` with some random data:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "DataProviderName")
  public static Object[][] getData(){
    Object[][] data = { {1, 2}, {3, 3}};
    return data;
  }
```

What I want to do now, is feeding `DataProvider` with results returned from SQL query, for example ids. I have not seen any documentations about feeding `DataProvider` with data returned from SQL queries. I've done sql connection and I can run a statement and store it into a list, but I can not store data into the `DataProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have the data from the SQL query stored in a list. Try iterating through your list when you initialize the DataProvider and adding the elements of the list to the array of Objects:

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataProviderName")
public static Object[] getData() {
    Object[] data = new Object[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        data[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return data;
}
```

I know, you have a two dimensional array but I don't know how you list looks. But I think you get the idea.